# Start Application as specific user from LaunchDaemon

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am currently trying to launch an Application in `/Applications` from a LaunchDaemon as specific user. Is there a way that I can launch this application without giving the program root privileges? I am writing the Daemon in objective C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue in a little quirky way now. I use `NSTask` in conjunction with `sudo` and `open`. Maybe someone needs this in the future:

```
+ (bool)start_app_bundle_as_user:(NSString *)path with_user_name:(NSString *)user_name
{
    NSString *cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/usr/bin/sudo -i -u %@ -- open -a %@", user_name, path];
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c", cmd, nil];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
    [task setArguments:args];
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];
    return [task terminationStatus] == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your launch daemon's plist, which should reside in /Library/LaunchDaemons, you can set the `UserName` key:

```
<key>UserName</key>
<string>userForThisProcess</string>
```

where `userForThisProcess` is the user you want to use to run the application.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me: I want to launch a process from a root daemon as specific user. I solved this by using NSTask in conjunction with sudo.

Comment: Then perhaps [this would help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474249/launching-a-user-context-application-by-root-daemon-on-demand).